# Showing that two topologies on the unit circle are the same

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Consider the unit circle, described two ways. The first is as a quotient space, as in [What does it mean to "identify" points of a topological space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438625/what-does-it-mean-to-identify-points-of-a-topological-space). (I'm using the first definition of its topology from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space) Let's call this version [0,1]/~.
The second is as a set of points in the complex plane, as in http://www.maths.bristol.ac.uk/~maxcu/Rotations.pdf. Let's call this version $S^{1}$. This second link defines a metric distance based on arc length. How can I show that the topology generated by this metric is the same as the quotient space topology?

**What I'm trying:**

I'm trying to show that the map $\phi: [0,1]/$~ $\rightarrow S^{1}$ defined by $\phi([x]) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is a homeomorphism. Note that it's a bijection.

To show that the map is open:

Suppose $U$ is an open set in [0,1]/~. Then $\cup_{[a] \in U}[a]$ is open in [0,1] (using the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$). So $\cup_{[a] \in U}[a]$ = $[0,1] \cap \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathring{I_{n}} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}([0,1] \cap \mathring{I_{n}})$ where $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathring{I}$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals. Then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}([0,1] \cap \mathring{I_{n}})$ is also a countable disjoint union of open intervals, viewing [0,1] as a topological space. It suffices to show that each $\phi([0,1] \cap \mathring{I_{n}})$ is open in the metric of $S^{1}$. If $[0,1] \cap \mathring{I_{n}}$ is the empty set, then we're o.k. Say $\mathring{I_{n}} = (a_{n},b_{n})$ is contained in (0,1). Let $e^{2\pi i x} \in \mathbb{C}$ be in $\phi(\mathring{I_{n}})$. Let $\delta = min \{d(e^{2\pi i a_{n}},e^{2\pi i x}), d(e^{2\pi i b_{n}},e^{2\pi i x})\}$.

We claim $B_{\delta}(e^{2\pi i x})\subseteq \phi(\mathring{I_{n}})$. Let $ e^{2\pi i y} \in B_{\delta}(e^{2\pi i x})$. Then $d(e^{2\pi i y},e^{2\pi i x}) < \delta$. i.e. $min(1-|x-y|,|x-y|) < min(1-|x-a_{n}|,|x-a_{n}|,1-|x-b_{n}|,|x-b_{n}|)$. We'd be done if we could should that $|a_{n}| < |y| < |b_{n}|$. I've played around with cases a bit, but have gotten stuck. Any hints or suggestions? Am I making this too messy? Are the two topologies even the same?

Thanks, and regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both topologies make the unit circle a compact Hausdorff space, it is sufficient to show that $\phi \colon [0,\,1]/\sim \to S^1,\; \phi([x]) = e^{2\pi i x}$ is a continuous bijection.

That it is a bijection follows from elementary properties of the exponential functions resp $\sin$ and $\cos$, and the continuity follows from general properties of quotient topologies, since the lift to $[0,\,1]$ is continuous.

Since $[0,\,1]/\sim$ is compact, every continuous mapping into a Hausdorff space is closed (a closed subspace of $[0,\,1]/\sim$ is compact, hence its image is compact, hence closed).

A closed and continuous bijection is a homeomorphism.