# One point compatification of $(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, compactification

> What is the one point compactification of $X=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$?

I think that the answer might be two circles in the plane sharing one tangent point but I don't know how to prove it properly.

What I thought was start with the set $(-1,0]\cup [0,1)$ obtained by adjoining the point $0$ to $X$. That (I thought) is homeomorphic to two circles with a common tangen point, since if we take that tangent point we should get two disjoint open intervals on the real line which I thought it might be homeomorphic to my original space $X$ because any two open intervals are homeomorphic.

If this is right, how can I translate it into proper mathematical language? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got the right goal! Unfortunately, you're off track, since $(-1,0]\cup[0,1)=(-1,1)$ is non-compact. One thing you might try instead is to consider the quotient of $[-1,1]/\{-1,0-1\}.$ You can adapt the approach shown in the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/329628/28900).

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks you! I liked the idea of taking the quotient a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one-point compactification of $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ is indeed the wedge of two circles. You can prove it as follows:

As a set, the compactification is $(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\cup\{*\}$. Map it to $S^1\vee S^1$ by sending $*$ to the point where the two circles join and the two segments homeomorphically onto the two circles missing a point. This map is obviously bijective. Now show that both it and its inverse are continuous using what you know about the topology of the compactification.

Comment: Thanks! Does $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\left(\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x)\right), \; & -1<x<1\\
\left( -\cos(2\pi x), \sin (2\pi x)\right),\;  &0<x<1\\
(0,0)\; & x= *
\end{cases}$$ work?

Comment: @user313212 If you want to embed $S^1\vee S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ and work with an explicit function, then it almost works (you have to move the centers of the circles, as it is they are one over the other...) Else you can also try to work more abstractly.

Comment: Oh, right, I've just realized that this would work onlly for the unit circle. I think adding or substracting $1$ would make the centers move to $(\pm 1, 0)$ which is what I need. I'll work on that. Thank you again!